# Custom dial pad DTMF tones are too loud

Tags: ios, audio, dtmf

I've a requirement of developing dial pad in my app, same like native iPhone phone application dial pad. I've added .wav files to my project for playing sound when clicked on the number buttons but they are too loud. But iPhone phone application dial pad sounds are smooth and not loud even in full volume. I'm using audio services framework and used this method AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundId); to play sound. Is there any way to lower volume ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ffmpeg` (`avconv` nowadays), `-h` says:

```
-vol volume         change audio volume (256=normal)
```

so run this for each file:

```
avconv -i file.wav -vol 100 file_lower.wav
```